# converting array of values to an  array of references

Tags: php

When I use `print_r` to examine the contents of this function `$arr` and `$refs` are the same.

Odd because this was a solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045875/pass-by-reference-problem-with-php-5-3-1) to the problems of passing `call_user_func_array` an array of references.

Does this function return an array of references or an array of values?

```
function makeValuesReferenced($arr){ 
    $refs = array(); 
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) 
        $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key]; 
    return $refs; 

}
```

Function Call:

```
print_r($db_->ref_arr(array(1,2,3,4)));
```

Results

```
Array ( [0] => 1 
        [1] => 2 
        [2] => 3 
        [3] => 4 )
```

Info. on prepared statements [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380657/prepared-statements-are-they-necessary)

Info. on  call_user_func_array [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381061/prepared-statements-creating-a-single-method)

Info. on the neccessity of references for call_user_func_array [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045875/pass-by-reference-problem-with-php-5-3-1)

**Does this function return an array of references or an array of values?**

Update:  using var_dump and adding & to parameter gives similar results...adds verification that ints are being returned.

> 1 2 3 4 array(4) { [0]=> &int(1) [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045875/pass-by-reference-problem-with-php-5-3-1)=> &int(2) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380657/prepared-statements-are-they-necessary)=> &int(3) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381061/prepared-statements-creating-a-single-method)=>
>   &int(4) }

Comment: change the values in arr and see if the values in ref change

Comment: I'm not sure that referenced and value variables will look any different. What is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question in the form of a question?

Comment: If the memory chip comment was aimed at me, I'm not sure what it was meant to represent. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your function does not return an array of references.
If you want to return an array of references, change to:

```
function makeValuesReferenced(&$arr){ 
    $refs = array(); 
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) 
        $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key]; 
    return $refs; 

}
```

PS: You should use `var_dump` to check.

Comment: This is called `Passing by Reference`.

Comment: print_r only print out the value, var_dump can show you whether it is a reference.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative way of doing this that involves a helper function.

```
//Helper function
function makeValueReferenced(&$value) {
    return $value;
}

function makeValuesReferenced($array) {
    return array_map("makeValueReferenced", $array);
}
```