# Making a function to query the Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, function

I am writing a script to access a specific detail about the user and I was hoping to make the database query be function.

```
function connectUser($ip) {
   $q = "SELECT * FROM users where ID='$ID'";
   $s = mysql_query($q);
   $r = mysql_fetch_array($s);
}
```

But when I try and use it it will not access the row the way I want it to.

```
$user = '999';
connectUser($user)
echo $r['name'];
```

But if I put echo $r['name']; in the function it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the variable `$r` isn't being returned by the function, so it's never being set outside of the function. Here's what you should have:

```
function connectUser($ip) {
   $q = "SELECT * FROM users where ID='$ip'";
   $s = mysql_query($q);
   return mysql_fetch_array($s);
}
```

And then outside have:

```
$user = '999';
$r = connectUser($user)
echo $r['name'];
```

You might also want to take a look at this question: [prepared statements - are they necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380657/prepared-statements-are-they-necessary)

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. Also I realize that I was serving the variable called $ip which was a mistake when writing this post. It didn't cause an issue on my code.

Answer (score 1):

your function is not returning anything. add `return $r['name']` at the end of function. 
then `echo connectUser($user);`

Answer (score 1):

thare are 2 major problems in your code

1. the function doesn't return anything and you don't assign it's result to a variable.
2. Your variables doesn't match. `$ip` doesn't seem the same variable with `$ID`

so, this one would work

```
function connectUser($id) { 
   $q = "SELECT * FROM users where ID=".intval($id); 
   $s = mysql_query($q); 
   return mysql_fetch_array($s); 
} 

$user = '999'; 
$r = connectUser($user) 
echo $r['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is not working,
as you did not supplied the database connection into function,
and you did not return anything ([PHP will return NULL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php))

Please understand what is [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) first,
and the [function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)

A workable example, can be like :-

```
function connectUser($db, $ip) 
{
  $q = "SELECT * FROM users where ID='$ID'"; // vulnerable for sql injection
  $s = mysql_query($q, $db);                 // should have error checking
  return mysql_fetch_array($s);              // value to be returned
}
```

How to use :-

```
$db = mysql_connect(...);
$res = connectUser($db, "some value");
```

Comment: The database was already connected and as I mentioned it worked when the function was echoing the variable.